# Unable to create a contact within a specified label, in google people api

Tags: laravel, google-workspace, google-people-api

I programmatically created a new label and obtained the corresponding label ID as a response mentioned below.

**contactGroups/47b2ea780fbdabe**

Using above Id, i am trying to add the contact details inside the specified label. Please find the code below for reference,

```
    $peopleService = new Google_Service_PeopleService($client);

    $person = new Google_Service_PeopleService_Person();

    $names = new Google_Service_PeopleService_Name();
    $names->setGivenName('Shankari');
    $names->setFamilyName('s');
    $person->setNames([$names]);

    $email = new Google_Service_PeopleService_EmailAddress();
    $email->setValue('shankari.s@example.com');
    $person->setEmailAddresses([$email]);

    $membership = new Google_Service_PeopleService_ContactGroupMembership();
    $membership->setContactGroupResourceName($folderId);
    $person->setMemberships([$membership]);

    $createdContact = $peopleService->people->createContact($person);
```

The above code does not show any error, but still the contact is not been reflected in contacts page.

Please let me know the fixes on the above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below method to create a contact inside folder.

```
$url = 'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:createContact';
$apiKey = 'ya29.a0AfB_byBSDKnAiK32W8ASZrCcV3jxor0ff8venN5k'; // access_token

$data = [
    "emailAddresses" => [
        [
            "value" => 'test@gmail.com',
        ]
    ],
    "names" => [
        [
            "givenName" => 'Test User',
        ]
    ],
    "phoneNumbers" => [
        [
            "value" => '71950XXXXX',
        ]
    ],
    "memberships" => [
        [
            "contactGroupMembership" => [
                "contactGroupResourceName" => (string) $folderId,
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

$response = Http::withHeaders([
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $apiKey,
])->post($url, $data);

$result = $response->json();
```

Folder Id includes **"contactGroups/55f5e6YYYZZZ54b3"**